# Socket.io 3 and PHP integration

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket

I using PHP SocketIO class to connect NodeJS application and send messages.
Everything worked wonderfully with Socket.io 2 but after upgrade to version 3 the PHP integration is stopped working.

When I send request I am getting this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: hNcappwZIQEbMz7ZGWS71lNcROc=
```

But I don't see anything on NodeJS side, even when I tried to log any connection to the server by using "connection" event.

This is the PHP class:

```
class SocketIO
{
    /**
     * @param null $host - $host of socket server
     * @param null $port - port of socket server
     * @param string $action - action to execute in sockt server
     * @param null $data - message to socket server
     * @param string $address - addres of socket.io on socket server
     * @param string $transport - transport type
     * @return bool
     */
    public function send($host = null, $port = null, $action= "message",  $data = null, $address = "/socket.io/?EIO=2", $transport = 'websocket')
    {
        $fd = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);
        
        if (!$fd) {
            return false;
        } //Can't connect tot server
        $key = $this->generateKey();
        $out = "GET $address&transport=$transport HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out.= "Host: https://$host:$port\r\n";
        $out.= "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n";
        $out.= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
        $out.= "Sec-WebSocket-Key: $key\r\n";
        $out.= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
        $out.= "Origin: https://$host\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fd, $out);

        // 101 switching protocols, see if echoes key
        $result= fread($fd,10000);

        preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Accept:\s(.*)$#mU', $result, $matches);

        $keyAccept = trim($matches[1]);
        $expectedResonse = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($key . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        $handshaked = ($keyAccept === $expectedResonse) ? true : false;

        if ($handshaked){
            fwrite($fd, $this->hybi10Encode('42["' . $action . '", "' . addslashes($data) . '"]'));
            fread($fd,1000000);
            return true;
        } else {return false;}
    }
    private function generateKey($length = 16)
    {
        $c = 0;
        $tmp = '';
        while ($c++ * 16 < $length) { $tmp .= md5(mt_rand(), true); }
        return base64_encode(substr($tmp, 0, $length));
    }
    private function hybi10Encode($payload, $type = 'text', $masked = true)
    {
        $frameHead = array();
        $payloadLength = strlen($payload);
        switch ($type) {
            case 'text':
                $frameHead[0] = 129;
                break;
            case 'close':
                $frameHead[0] = 136;
                break;
            case 'ping':
                $frameHead[0] = 137;
                break;
            case 'pong':
                $frameHead[0] = 138;
                break;
        }
        if ($payloadLength > 65535) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%064b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 255 : 127;
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $frameHead[$i + 2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[$i]);
            }
            if ($frameHead[2] > 127) {
                $this->close(1004);
                return false;
            }
        } elseif ($payloadLength > 125) {
            $payloadLengthBin = str_split(sprintf('%016b', $payloadLength), 8);
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? 254 : 126;
            $frameHead[2] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[0]);
            $frameHead[3] = bindec($payloadLengthBin[1]);
        } else {
            $frameHead[1] = ($masked === true) ? $payloadLength + 128 : $payloadLength;
        }
        foreach (array_keys($frameHead) as $i) {
            $frameHead[$i] = chr($frameHead[$i]);
        }
        if ($masked === true) {
            $mask = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                $mask[$i] = chr(rand(0, 255));
            }
            $frameHead = array_merge($frameHead, $mask);
        }
        $frame = implode('', $frameHead);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $payloadLength; $i++) {
            $frame .= ($masked === true) ? $payload[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4] : $payload[$i];
        }
        return $frame;
    }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem with all the libraries that exists on github, the problem is that they are abandoned or not updated to socket.io V3.

In socket.io documentation says:

> TL;DR: due to several breaking changes, a v2 client will not be able to connect to a v3 server (and vice versa)

To solve this problem, you need to learn how socket.io client works, this is easy because is in the protocol documentation, in the sample-session section.

[Socket.Io protocol documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol#sample-session)

To solve this, you will need to forget the fsockopen and fwrite functions, you need to use CURL directly doing the requests mentioned in the protocol documentation.

**Request n°1** 
*GET* 
*url*: /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N8hyd7H
*Open packet:* Open the connection between php and socket.io server. The server will return a "session id" named "sid", you will be adding this to the url query for the subsecuent queries.

**Request n°2** 
*POST* 
*url*: /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N8hyd7H&sid=sessionIdFromRequest1
*post body*: '40'
*Namespace connection request*: You need to send in the body the number 40, as a string, this means that you want to connect to socket.io "message" type

**Request n°3** 
*GET* 
*url*: /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N8hyd7H&sid=sessionIdFromRequest1
*Namespace connection approval* : This will return if the connection is successful or if there is an error, here is when the socket.io server authorizes your connection if you need a token.

**Request n°4**
*POST*
*url*: /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N8hyd7H&sid=sessionIdFromRequest1
*post body*: 42[event,data] 
For example 42["notifications","Hi, Im a notification"] and is equivalent to socket.emit(event,data)
*Emit message to server*: Send your message to the socket.io server.

Here is a BASIC example using Symfony 5.2 and HttpClientInterface:

```
<?php

// install dependencies before: composer require symfony/http-client

use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\CurlHttpClient;

include('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new CurlHttpClient();
sendToSocket($client);

function sendToSocket(HttpClientInterface $client)
{
    $first = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N8hyd6w');
    $res = ltrim($first->getContent(), '0');
    $res = json_decode($res, true);
    $sid = $res['sid'];

    $second = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid='.$sid, [
            'body' => '40'
        ]);
    $third = $client->request('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid='.$sid);

    $fourth = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid='.$sid, [
        'body' => '42["notifications","Hi, Im a notification"]'
    ]);

}
```

As you can see, is very easy, and you dont need the troubling "copy-pasted" libraries out there. I said "copy-pasted" because all use the same code to open de socket and send the information, but no one is compatible with socket.io V3.

Here is an image, proving that the given code works as January 4 2021 with php 7.4, symfony 5.2 and socket.io V3.

[image: Socket.io v3 php]

This is my test server in node

```
// Install dependencies before: npm i express socket.io

const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
   cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"]
   }
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

   console.log("New Connection with transport", socket.conn.transport.name);

   socket.on('notifications', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Server started port 3000');
});
```

I need to say that this solution works excellent if you want to send "one direction" messages to your socket.io server, like a new notification or whatever that doesn't need a permanent connection, is just "one shot" and nothing else.

Happy coding and greetings from Mexico.

Here is another example:
[image: Socket.io v3 php]

First column is Postman making a request to the php server, simulating a server side event, like a new question created. In the response are the dumps of the response body from the 4 requests that you need to make.

Second column is the socket.IO node server running on port 3000

And the last column is the chrome console, simulating a user connected to the socket.IO server via websocket looking for notifications in 'questions' event.

Comment: I figured out that "Request n°3" is not necessary, I just did it with 3 requests in POSTMAN:
1. GET
2. POST (with sid from GET) with "40" in body
3. POST (with sid from GET) with "42['chanel name','message']"

Comment: This works but most of the times it throws error for session id unknown.  {
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Session ID unknown"
} . Anyone can help with any php emitter to emit one time event to socket.io

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to add the namespace in the first request, should I switch to post request?