# Grab the race number from a tracking software

Tags: php, websocket

[image]

I want to grab this number (28/28) with PHP from a tracking software (https://aircrasher.livefpv.com/live/scoring/) for drone races. But I can't. I think it's a websocket, but I don't know how to retrieve information from it. I tried curl, I tried the "ultimate-web-scraper" from GitHub (https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-web-scraper). I tried a code example from another post from here ([PHP simple web socket client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67314599/php-simple-web-socket-client)) but I'm not able to get this number. Is it imposible to get this number (with php)?

This is what I tried so far with the help of "ultimate-web-scraper" (https://kleesit.de/beta/livetime/webscraper/test.php):

```html
<?php
require_once "support/web_browser.php";
require_once "support/tag_filter.php";

// Retrieve the standard HTML parsing array for later use.
$htmloptions = TagFilter::GetHTMLOptions();

// Retrieve a URL (emulating Firefox by default).
$url = "https://aircrasher.livefpv.com/live/scoring/";
$web = new WebBrowser();
$result = $web->Process($url);

// Check for connectivity and response errors.
if (!$result["success"])
{
    echo "Error retrieving URL.  " . $result["error"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

if ($result["response"]["code"] != 200)
{
    echo "Error retrieving URL.  Server returned:  " . $result["response"]["code"] . " " . $result["response"]["meaning"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

// Get the final URL after redirects.
$baseurl = $result["url"];

// Use TagFilter to parse the content.
$html = TagFilter::Explode($result["body"], $htmloptions);

// Find all anchor tags inside a div with a specific class.
// A useful CSS selector cheat sheet:  https://gist.github.com/magicznyleszek/809a69dd05e1d5f12d01
echo "All the URLs:\n";
$result2 = $html->Find("div.someclass a[href]");
if (!$result2["success"])
{
    echo "Error parsing/finding URLs.  " . $result2["error"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

foreach ($result2["ids"] as $id)
{
    // Faster direct access.
    echo "\t" . $html->nodes[$id]["attrs"]["href"] . "\n";
    echo "\t" . HTTP::ConvertRelativeToAbsoluteURL($baseurl, $html->nodes[$id]["attrs"]["href"]) . "\n";
}

// Find all table rows that have 'th' tags.
// The 'tr' tag IDs are returned.
$result2 = $html->Filter($html->Find("tr"), "th");
if (!$result2["success"])
{
    echo "Error parsing/finding table rows.  " . $result2["error"] . "\n";
    exit();
}

foreach ($result2["ids"] as $id)
{
    echo "\t" . $html->GetOuterHTML($id) . "\n\n";
}
?>
```

This is what I tried with CURL and the help of a stackoverflow post (https://kleesit.de/beta/livetime/test2.php):

```html
<?php 
// random 7 chars digit/alphabet for "t" param
$random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7);
$socket_server='https://aircrasher.livefpv.com/live/scoring/';

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

//N°1 GET request
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    [
        CURLOPT_URL => $socket_server,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        // since it is TRUE by default we should disable it
        // on our localhost, but from real https server it will work with TRUE
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
    ]);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$output=substr($output, 1);

echo $socket_server;
// server response in my case was looking like that:
// '{"sid":"4liJK2jWEwmTykwjAAAR","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}'
var_dump($output);

$decod=json_decode($output);
// setting ping Interval accordingly with server response
$pingInterval = $decod->pingInterval;


//N°2 POST request
$socket_server_with_sid = $socket_server.'&sid='.$decod->sid;

curl_setopt_array(
    $ch,
    [
        CURLOPT_URL => $socket_server_with_sid,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => $pingInterval,
        // 4           => Engine.IO "message" packet type
        // 0           => Socket.IO "CONNECT" packet type
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '40'
    ]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

// ok
var_dump($output);

// Pervious 2 requests are called "hand shake" now we can send a message
// N°3 socket.emit
if ($output==='ok')  {
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch,
        [
            CURLOPT_URL => $socket_server_with_sid,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS => $pingInterval,
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            // 4           => Engine.IO "message" packet type
            // 2           => Engine.IO "EVENT" packet type
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '42["chat message","0devhost message 10"]'
        ]);
    
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    // ok
    echo $output.'<br/>';
    echo $socket_server_with_sid;
}

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: We don't know what "not able to" means because you haven't actually shown what you tried or what went wrong. Also "I think it's a websocket"...because? Bear in mind we're probably not going to go and debug that site for you, so you need to provide some concrete information. In other words, you need to get a lot more specific before we can help you easily. See also [ask], thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Post your code/attempt, example data, expected result from that data and what currently happens (we need details, incl. full error messages, if any.) Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). _"is it imposible to get this number (with php)?"_ - Without having analyzed how that page works (which we won't do for you), we can't really answer that question.